# motion tween problem

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, slider, motion

i wrote these pieces of code, but motion tween doesn't work. can you help me?

```
function loadXML(event:Event):void{

    sliderXML=XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    var menuXML:XML = XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
    xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());

    //var X:int = 100;

    for each(var listItem:XML in sliderXML..listItem){

             strTitle[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.itemTitle.toString();
             strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.posterLink.toString();
             strVideoLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.videoLink.toString();

             var _temp:Loader = new Loader();
             poster.splice(sliderMaxNum, 0, _temp);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].load(new URLRequest(strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum]));
             var posterClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();  //load the movieclip
             posterClip.addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);  //convert poster[sliderMaxNum] to movieClip
             addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].x = slider_bg.width;
             poster[sliderMaxNum].y = 28;

             poster[sliderMaxNum].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poster_click(sliderMaxNum));

             sliderMaxNum ++;
             }
    LastSliderNum = sliderMaxNum - 1;
    //*************************************************
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(poster[0], "x", Strong.easeOut, 500, 100, 5, true);
    myTween.start();
    //*************************************************
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation, by the way :3

Comment: Sorry, what did you say was in poster[0] again?

Comment: Hi user669636, could you tell us what actually you are trying to do and what the exact problem is? If you get any errors, you should share them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was testing xml slideshow, but tween was not working on flash window but on browser window it works , so thanks for reply